# Significance of ARM SysTick Timer vs. Other Timers?

Tags: arm, programming, cortex-m

I'm coming from 8 bit MCUs, and I've used a system timer to generate a periodic interrupt that seems to be the motivation behind the Cortex M SysTick timer?

Is there some kind of architectural significance to using the SysTick timer versus any other timer on the Cortex M MCUs?

Is it just a matter of coding preference, that programmers have used the SysTick timer as the primary every few ms timer?

The 800 page reference manual is pretty silent on SysTick other than how you apply post/prescalars.

I see it is a default high priority interrupt, so it kind of the path of least resistance for the system tick. But the interrupt priority is settable.

(The origin of this question is that I am using the STM32CubeMX to generate a project template, and when you go to add FreeRTOS, the Cube generates a warning that FreeRTOS should use a separate timer from SysTick... what makes me wonder if there something else at play here?  I has just assumed you would the SysTick because that is "how things are done"...).

Comment: SysTick is a standard ARM-defined timer. While the others are peripherals specific to the MCUs and not part of the core.

Comment: Does it have better latency than a peripheral timer?  Because it is standard to every Cortex M, is the motivation than portability of code?

Comment: I would guess the latency difference is negligible. It's a part of the core definition. I would say a core in it's minimum should have some minimal set of HW to be able to run some minimal SW. Without timers at all it won't be possible.

Comment: And I think this is always designed with an OS in mind. So one can have a somewhat universal portable kernel, and just have "drivers" for the variable hardware.

Comment: @Leroy105 Put in other words, you need to understand that ARM is a company (sold a year ago?) that does NOT fabricate CPUs but instead offers intellectual property (masks and/or synthesizable source) to those who will be directly fabricating such devices or brokering it out for fabrication. They stay out of the competition there. Those buying the IP from ARM will add their own peripherals to differentiate themselves from others. The SysTick is part of the ARM CORE IP. So *all* ARM manufacturers have it. Not all ARM have anything else, though. This makes SysTick unique. Make sense?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.  I got spooked with the FreeRTOS error from the cube thing.  I kind of assumed FreeRTOS would be clocked by SysTick. Maybe it is, and the error really means something else.  I'm porting over some code to learn an RTOS and get familiar with Cortex M.  The actual product will still be an 8051.

Comment: I strongly believe FreeRTOS is clocked by SysTick

Comment: @Jonk -- yeah, I totally get that end of it.  I didn't realize it was a defined core functional unit of every Cortex M.  I just see some 24 bit timer, that every newbie example uses and you start to wonder if there is some magic power or something going with this timer...

Comment: @Leroy105 If I were writing an O/S (and I do so, often), then I would make a judgment about SysTick on the basis of what I'm trying to achieve. If I didn't want to support the use of various timers, but wanted to "hard code" a timer that I could count on, then I'd use the SysTick. But if I wanted to provide "configurability," then I'd allow whomever is compiling the O/S to specify one to use, allowing them to use vendor-specific timers at their leisure.

Comment: One of these days, I'm going to have to put my O/S in the wild, so to speak. It's designed to allow all kinds of configuration choices that not even FreeRTOS offers and it supports extremely tiny chips with almost no RAM in them (by allowing some of the per-process constant data to be held in flash, instead.) Priorities are supported, for example. But if you know the number of actual processes at compile time and can specify their priorities then, there is no reason those values cannot be in flash. I'll release it if I ever get the time to better doc it, anyway.

Comment: @jonk OT: Is it a commercial/proprietary project? Or personal/opensource?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's my own that I started developing around 1990, when 32-bit cpus weren't often in embedded devices. I had to carefully isolate each and every piece, as a result. You can even configure whether or not you want singly, or doubly linked lists (RAM vs insert/delete speed trade-off) just using a #define to select which way you want to go. It supports cooperative-only, or pre-emption (though pre-emption has implications for the libraries.) Etc. Everything is configurable down to the byte level. I own it but feel no ownership of it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. FreeRTOS is often clocked by SysTick, but not always. I'm working on a low-power application where SysTick gets shut down in some states so FreeRTOS is clocked by one of the other timers.

Comment: @brhans Is it out-of-the box functionality or you had to extend the kernel?

Comment: @EugeneSh. You can read a small overview at [Overview, written back in 2008](http://www.infinitefactors.org/docs/stos.pdf).

Comment: @jonk Cool, thanks. Not so small though :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. You will also find it "partially edited." It's just something I started to write, thinking I might release it then. Then work impinged and I halted the effort. (You will see "notes to self" inside it, for example, which need further discussion and expansion.) Partly, this got a lot of expansion during my work on medical instruments where I could not buy, nor use, a commercial O/S since these were critical devices requiring proof of exercise of EVERY LINE OF CODE.

Comment: Totally off-topic, can anyone weigh in on this:  What is more efficient, running a Cortex M at lowest required frequency for the task and putting it to sleep (assuming optimimal peripheral shutdown, etc.), or running Cortex M at highest speed and putting it to sleep.  On my 8051 I found more efficiency at slowest clock.  PICs faster speeds.  Cortex Ms?

Comment: @Leroy105 Better put it as a different question, but define "efficient" before.

Comment: Appreciate any insight: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/350595/arm-cortex-m-power-consumption-sleeping-with-higher-clock-speeds-vs-lower-cl

Comment: @EugeneSh. Extended by the microcontroller vendor (SiLabs) as part of their 'stack'.

Comment: @Leroy105 what did the datasheet for the part say?  A cortex-m is just the core, arm doesnt make chips they make IP, the chip vendor buys that logic and makes a chip at some foundry with some process, leakage, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered in comments.

The SysTick if present is part of the ARM core, the other timers are from the chip vendor.  SysTick has a more direct event (think interrupt) to the core where the other times come in through interrupts, not that that matters.  And other timers tend to have more features.

You tagged Cortex-M so this is likely a microcontroller which means you might be doing baremetal which means you can do whatever you want, you decide what timers do what.  If you take some already made RTOS or OS for that chip then they have decided what resources they want to consume and why.  Primarily opinion based as far as that goes.

The systick timer is a lot easier and simpler to get going, and isnt always present, some cores dont have it as an option at all and some as an option (for the chip vendor to decide at compile time), so it has that advantage, although there may be some timers in some chips that are equally simple.

Chip vendor timers can sometimes drive I/O pins or have some external involvement where the systick is AFAIK contained within the core.